# Discord Python - How to make bot receive message under if message.content

Tags: discord.py

Sorry for my english but i need help
Can i make bot receive message under if message.content

```
async def on_message(message):
    message_loop = message.content
    if message.content == "!run":
        await message.delete()
        random_difficult = ['{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),]

        choice_difficult = random.choice(random_difficult).lower()
        await message.channel.send(choice_difficult)
        game_embed= discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_blue())
        game_embed.set_image(url='https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text={}'.format(choice_difficult))
        game_embed.set_author(name='... Arcade Game',icon_url='http://mqt-web.tk/image/RBS-Logo.png')
        game_embed.set_footer(text='Power by ....', icon_url='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png')
        game_embed.add_field(name='TEXT', value='TEXT', inline=True)
        game_embed.add_field(name='TIME LIMITE', value='20 Sec', inline=True)
        message_bot = await message.channel.send(embed=game_embed)
     
        start = True
        count = 0
        while start == True:
            count = count + 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if message.content == choice_difficult:
                #some code
            print(count)
```

I have no idea to do

Comment: `if message.content == "stop":` is what your looking for I believe

Comment: Thanks for reply But it not work

Comment: Where is `character` defined?

Comment: Sorry i edit some code. now no error

Comment: but nothing when i type in discord channel

Comment: Jawad
This is my character define

`character = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","y","j","k","m","n","o","p","q","r","u","w","s","z"
            ,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","Y","J","K","M","N","O","P","Q","R","U","W","S","Z"
            ,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wait_for` for this. Because it won't work in `on_message` event. You should use it in a command like this:

```
@client.commnad()
async def run(ctx):
        await message.delete()
        random_difficult = ['{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),]

        choice_difficult = random.choice(random_difficult).lower()
        await message.channel.send(choice_difficult)
        game_embed= discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_blue())
        game_embed.set_image(url='https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text={}'.format(choice_difficult))
        game_embed.set_author(name='RobuxshopTH Arcade Game',icon_url='http://mqt-web.tk/image/RBS-Logo.png')
        game_embed.set_footer(text='Power by ....', icon_url='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png')
        game_embed.add_field(name='TEXT', value='TEXT', inline=True)
        game_embed.add_field(name='TIME LIMITE', value='20 Sec', inline=True)
        message_bot = await message.channel.send(embed=game_embed)
     
        start = True
        count = 0
        while start == True:
            count = count + 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await client.wait_for('message', check=choice_difficult, timeout=20)
```

You can delete the `timeout` parameter but if you do that and if the user never reponse like `choice_difficult`, it brings problems.

**EDIT**

You should put a function in `check` parameter like this:

```
def check():
    return choice_difficult
await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
```

So the new code is this:

```
@client.commnad()
async def run(ctx):
        await message.delete()
        random_difficult = ['{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),
                            '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character),random.choice(character)),]

        choice_difficult = random.choice(random_difficult).lower()
        await message.channel.send(choice_difficult)
        game_embed= discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_blue())
        game_embed.set_image(url='https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text={}'.format(choice_difficult))
        game_embed.set_author(name='RobuxshopTH Arcade Game',icon_url='http://mqt-web.tk/image/RBS-Logo.png')
        game_embed.set_footer(text='Power by ....', icon_url='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png')
        game_embed.add_field(name='TEXT', value='TEXT', inline=True)
        game_embed.add_field(name='TIME LIMITE', value='20 Sec', inline=True)
        message_bot = await message.channel.send(embed=game_embed)
        def check():
            return choice_difficult
        start = True
        count = 0
        while start == True:
            count = count + 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
```

Comment: Thx,But it not work I got this error 
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I edited the answer so this must work.

Comment: and i try `await client.wait_for('message', check=check(), timeout=20)` and get this error : https://prnt.sc/u9z4po

Comment: This link help me :https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for